# Google Chrome renders Google Font differently

Tags: css, fonts, less, rendering

I'm experiencing some major differences in font rendering (Google Font) on Win7 in Google Chrome browser. When Google Font is called via **@import** into LESS file, render is OK, but when I copy paste the same content of the file that is imported, I get distorted font.

Any ideas, why this is happening? I need to avoid @import due the Google PageSpeed optimization guidelines.

When Google Font is called via **@import** into LESS file, render is OK: http://cl.ly/Wtqb/o
Code is the following:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,700,600,300&subset=latin,latin-ext);
```

But, when Google Font is called **directly** into LESS file, render gets distorted: http://cl.ly/WuOp/o

Code is the following:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/DXI1ORHCpsQm3Vp6mXoaTeY5mlVXtdNkpsMpKkrDXP4.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/u-WUoqrET9fUeobQW7jkRbO3LdcAZYWl9Si6vvxL-qU.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  src: local('Open Sans Semibold'), local('OpenSans-Semibold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/MTP_ySUJH_bn48VBG8sNSuY5mlVXtdNkpsMpKkrDXP4.woff) format('woff');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  src: local('Open Sans Bold'), local('OpenSans-Bold'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/opensans/v8/k3k702ZOKiLJc3WVjuplzOY5mlVXtdNkpsMpKkrDXP4.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Comment: You image seems to show IE(11) whilst your question is about chrome? Make sure that the compiled CSS loads before the usage of the font.

Comment: No, It's chrome on Windows, it's not IE.